# Finding solutions to $y^2 = x^3 - 27$

Tags: diophantine-equations, mordell-curves

I am trying to find integer solutions to this equation:

$$ y^2 = x^3 - 27 $$

With the other problem I tried I was able to use unique factorization in $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{n}]$. I don't know how to get started on this one. I tried looking online and there's some stuff about elliptic curves but I don't understand them.

Here's what I tried so far:

$x$ is odd since otherwise $y^2 = -27 = 5 \mod 8$ but $5$ is not a square mod $8$ also $y$ is even.

$ x^3 = y^2 + 27 $

$ x^3 = (y + 3\sqrt{-3})(y-3\sqrt{-3})$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ which is unique prime factorization.

Any common divisor must divide $6\sqrt{-3}$ and so norm of common divisor must divide $108$?

???

Thanks for any help, sorry English is not my first language.

*edit*: Here's some new work:

Let $d$ be greatest common divisor of $y+3\sqrt{-3}$ and $y-3\sqrt{-3}$. then $N(d) | 108$ and $N(d) | y^2 + 27 $, this is odd number. $N(d)$ is odd number so $N(d) = 1, 3, 9, 27$. (I know really I need $N(d) = 27$ because that gives $y=0$.)

Comment: https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/36/a/3 says there is only one solution (3,0).

Answer (score 4):

It seems the following.

This equation is a special case of the Mordell equation, $y^2 =x^3 +A$. A tremendous amount of work has been done on the Mordell equation, and solutions have been tabulated for large ranges of values of $A $, for example,  [here](http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL+).

Also it is new for me that you consider a non-natural factorization. We have $(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)=y^2$. Put $a=GCD(x-3,x^2+3x+9)$. It is easy to show that $a|27,$ so it rests to solve the systems 
$$\cases{
x-3=du^2\\
x^2+3x+9=dv^2},$$ where $u$ and $v$ are coprime and $d=3^k$, $0\le k\le 3$. For instance, for $d=1,9$ we obtain $(x+1)^2<(\sqrt{d}v)^2<(x+2)^2$  provided $x>5$, so we have $x=3$. I'll think about the cases $d=3,27$.

Assume $d=3$. Then $x=3(u^2+1)$. So

$$3^2(u^2+1)^2+3^2(u^2+1)+3^2=3v^2$$

$$3(u^2+1)^2+3(u^2+1)+3=v^2$$

So $v=3w$ and

$$(u^2+1)^2+(u^2+1)+1=3w^2$$

$$u^4+2u^2+1+u^2+1+1=3w^2$$

$$u^4+3u^2+3=3w^2$$

Then $u$ is divisible by $3$ too, a contradiction, because $u$ and $v$ are coprime.

Assume $d=27$. Then $x=3(3^2u^2+1)$. So

$$3^2(3^2u^2+1)^2+3^2(3^2u^2+1)+3^2=3^3v^2$$

$$(3^2u^2+1)^2+(3^2u^2+1)+1=3v^2,$$

$$3^4u^4+2\cdot 3^2u^2+1+3^2u^2+1+1=3v^2,$$

$$3^3u^4+3^2u^2+1=v^2$$

My program checked $1\le u\le 2\cdot 10^4$ and found no solutions.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $(x-3)(x^2+3x+9) = y^2$? If so, then $a = \gcd(x-3,x^2+3x+9) \mid 27$ not $21$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Oops, I corrected this. Thanks.

Comment: Also, how do you solve the resulting system for $d = 3$? That was where I got stuck.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I don’t know its solution, I only formulated it and it looks easier than the initial equation.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I have solved the resulting system for $d=3$, so it remains only the case $d=27$.

Comment: factor $y^2+27$ instead and use that ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ has class number 1.